# Is it possible to rename a non-`final` variable to a `final` name style or the other way around in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, naming-conventions

in Java, non-`final` variables use the naming convention of an uppercase for every first letter of a word: `myInteger`.
`final` variables use all uppercase letters and an underscore for word separation: `MY_INTEGER`.

In Eclipse, one can rename a varialbe using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and that takes care of all references. My question is: is there a way to easily rename a varialbe between the `final` and non-`final` styles. Otherwise, I need to retype more or less the whole name.

Comment: Let's assume there is a way, how will you change the places where you actually use the variable?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'm not changing the place, just the name and references. It's a regular renaming just as if you made a typo and trying to fix it.

Comment: Refactoring is your best option.

Comment: The upper case style is usually only used for `static final`

Comment: @MarounMaroun The whole question is about refactoring -> renaming. I'm looking for an option to make it easier instead of retyping.

Comment: I mean using ALT + SHIFT + R (it's also the safest).

Comment: @MarounMaroun That's what I wrote in the question...

Comment: @greg-449 I see the uppercase style on local method variables which are only `final` (can't be `static` anyway). In any case, the question is technical, not debating code conventions.

Comment: @user1803551 Naming local variables like a constant (all letters uppercase) just shows that the developer has no idea what he's doing. May check his code for other smells.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly this is what you are expecting: an automatic way of changing the coding style of a name used for a variable (I'm skipping the word final deliberately, because *final* means its value can't be changed and thus not a variable). That is, MY_INTEGER to myInteger and *vice versa*. If that's correct then I think the answer is *no* in Eclipse.

Comment: Yes, that's the functionality I was looking for. Eclipse does warn you if you use lowercase for class names for example, and offers to correct it for you. I thought there would be a similar functionality for fields, but apparently there isn't.

Comment: Here's a partial good news! I just happened to run into this situation. I just wanted to change `private static final Ignite IGNITE = ...` to `private static Ignite ignite = ...`. I removed the keyword `final`, highlighted the name 'IGNITE' & pressed CTRL-Space to get `ignite`, and _vice versa_.

Comment: That was the partial good news, in case you haven't tried yet. I was going to complete it but my 5 minutes limit to edit a comment was over. Here's the full text I was planning to add: "Here's a partial good news! I just happened to run into this situation. I wanted to change `private static final Ignite IGNITE = ...` to `private static Ignite ignite = ...`. I removed the keyword `final`, highlighted the name `IGNITE` & pressed CTRL-Space to get `ignite`, and _vice versa_. Of course, this works only when the names of the Class and its instance are the same except for the case."

Comment: Ah, I must have read the unfinished comment. The CTRL + SPACE is the regular content assist. You are right that it does take into account the `static final` modifier. This would be great if, as you said, it wasn't limited to the class's name. I would integrate that "discovery" into your answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the "rename" refactoring feature of the IDE to change the variable name. You cannot change the "style" of a name in Java because that is not a Java concept. What you change is the name of the variable.

Also, you don't use uppercase-plus-underscore names for `final` variables, you use them for constant variables, or by extension, `final` references to immutable objects. `final` references to mutable objects use camel case with an initial lower-case letter. Not all `final` variables are constants.